# Sample string for throwing UnsupportedEncodingException for URLDecoder.decode()

Tags: java, exception, encoding

Can anyone please suggest a sample string(value for sampleString) for getting
`UnsupportedEncodingException` in the below given code snippet.

```
public static String decode(String sampleString)  
{  
    try {   
         return URLDecoder.decode(sampleString, "UTF-8" );  
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {  
         return "Issue while decoding" +e.getMessage();  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stright from implementation of URLDecoder.decode(String, String)

```
if (enc.length() == 0) {
        throw new UnsupportedEncodingException ("URLDecoder: empty string enc   parameter");
}
```

So its

```
URLDecoder.decode(sampleString, "" );
```

to throw the exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But what I require is the value of the sample string without changing UTF8

Answer (score 0):

UEE would only be for the encoding/charset IMHO, `URLDecoder.decode(sampleString, "DOS")` where the encoding "DOS" is not available. The only problem could be a wrong %-encoding. U+2015, HORIZONTAL BAR, would be %E2%80%95 which could be written wrong as %95 (a continuation byte). "" for the encoding would certainly give an UUE.